# What are the differences between Proximal Policy Optimization versions PPO1 and PPO2?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, reference-request, proximal-policy-optimization

When [**Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO)**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) was released, it was accompanied by a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) describing it.

Later, the authors at OpenAI introduced a second version of PPO, called [PPO2](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/ppo2/) (whereas the original version is now commonly referred to as [PPO1](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/ppo1)). Unfortunately, the several changes made between PPO1 and PPO2 are pretty much undocumented (as stated over [here](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html)).

Someone associated with OpnenAI's [baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines) Deep Reinforcement Learning repository [commented](https://github.com/openai/baselines/issues/485#issuecomment-413722708) that the main advancement of PPO2 (compared to PPO1) was the use of a more advanced parallelism strategy, leading to improved performance. Unfortunately, the person omitted naming further changes made.

*Now, I was wondering if anyone is aware of a (reliable) source of information or (preferably) even some published literature that lists **all the numerous differences** between PPO1 and PPO2.*